# Export Data to MS Word (.doc) in Servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, export-to-word

I'm creating an export screen in servlet, in Which user can using search function and get the result in Ms Word(.doc) format. 
 I tried to query data from Database and create .doc file directly using

- Apache POI
- Docx4j

But I faced with the complicacy of make output file in form.

I want to know, are there any way that I can create a template file in advanced, and fill out the data to template to create output .doc file and stream to client or convert to Doc file from another format like : HTML file, etc ?

Thank in advanced !

Answer (score 0):

Use JasperReports and iReport.

http://www.jaspersoft.com/

It can export to "HTML, PDF, Excel, OpenOffice and Word", although I'd stick with PDF.

I would be interested to see if there are alternative ways to make a populatable report template.

If you just want to generate a word file, the easiest way is to lie to the browser and output an HTML version of the report and pretend its a word document. Then:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""
            + reportName + ".doc\"");
response.setContentType("application/msword");
```

Browsers will pass the file on to the file to whatever handles .doc files, and both MS Word and OpenOffice writer are smart enough to recognise that the .doc file actually contains HTML. If you give it a ".html" extension, some browsers just show the contents.